# How to create an Angular 2+ *ngFor filled table with a record in every cell?

Tags: html, css, angular, html-table, ngfor

I'm trying to create a responsive table with undefined number of rows and columns in which every cell is filled with a record occurrence of an Angular 2+ *ngFor.

For example, if my array has 9 records and my page size contains only 4 in each row, I want 3 rows with 4 columns and with this order:

```
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |

| 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |

| 9 |
```

In this case, my array is similar to:

```
imgList = [
    {name: '1', path: '/images/first/'},
    {name: '2', path: '/images/second/'},
    {name: '3', path: '/images/third/'},
    {name: '4', path: '/images/etc/'},
    {name: '5', path: '/images/etc/'},
    {name: '6', path: '/images/etc/'},
    {name: '7', path: '/images/etc/'},
    {name: '8', path: '/images/etc/'},
    {name: '9', path: '/images/etc/'}
];
```

and the html is:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <div *ngFor="let image of imgList">
      {{image.name}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

At now my images are not formatted in a table, how can I a drow one with explained style?

Thank to all.
G.

Comment: Can you post your code, so that we can help you from here ?

Comment: Sure, I modified my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need logic to slice the array up into rows(2d array).

https://stackblitz.com/edit/record-in-every-cell?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Update:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/record-in-every-cell-update?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Update 2:
Added `trackImage` function for `NgForOf`'s `ngForTrackBy`, may help angular reuse elements if UI gets more complicated. (edit: tested, yes this works somewhat if you have a trackBy for each ngFor, example: if you switch between 4 and 3 columns it re-renders the td elements with 7 and 8 in it between the beginning of the  3rd and end of the 2nd row, but resuses the element with 9 init, but w/o trackBy it re-renders everything every time columns changes)

Comment: OMG, this is so easy and so clean! Thanks a lot, really!